# How can I split "+" so my form can calculate user input

Tags: c#, winforms

My current code will run but is crashes when I try to enter something like 2+2. My goal is to solve the problem in the textbox a user enters so it can be displayed in richtextbox as the asnwer. which is just addition right now.

```
int sum;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{    
  if ((char)Keys.Enter == e.KeyChar)
  {
    if(textBox1.Text.Contains("+"))
    {
      String[] data = Text.Split('+');
      int sum = Int32.Parse(data[0]) + Int32.Parse(data[1]);
    }
    richTextBox1.Text += " = " + textBox1.Text + "\n";
    textBox1.Clear();  
    textBox1.Focus();       
  }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`

Comment: What are your two data values?  Use the debugger.

Comment: `= Text.Split('+');` - here `.Text` will be the *Forms* caption. Use `textBox1.Text` instead.

Comment: You are also declaring your `sum` variable twice.

Comment: ..but never use any of it. Also: you NEED to do a check on the result of the split!  Maybe if (data .Length == 2)..

Comment: The adding of the two split data[] is the problem. The data values are decide by user input. For example, they enter 5 + 7 i would hold 5 and 7 in a data[]

Comment: @JeremiahCrosby, if you re-read what Alex K. commented on you will see your issue.

Comment: You need to learn [How to Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your not saving your text from textboxt1 besides checking it in the if statement.  I commented out your line of code and wrote some new code above that line.  I didn't get a chance to test this so let me know if it does not work.

```
 public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{    
    if ((char)Keys.Enter == e.KeyChar)

    {    if(textBox1.Text.Contains("+"))
        {
              String[] data = textBox1.Text.Split("+");
            //String[] data = Text.Split('+');

            int sum = Int32.TryParse(data[0]) + Int32.TryParse(data[1]);
           //int sum = Int32.Parse(data[0]) + Int32.Parse(data[1]);



        }




        richTextBox1.Text += " = " + textBox1.Text + "\n";
        textBox1.Clear();  
        textBox1.Focus();





    }

}
```

Comment: what's with the formatting? Also String doesn't have a method called `split`. Did you intend to write `Split`? Same with `int32` and `Int32`.

Comment: I'm still having uses with = textbox1 does not exist in context according to C# same for int32. With split all I want to do is convert data[] into int so it can be calculated and returned to richtextbox

Comment: @JeremiahCrosby c# is case-sensitive.  Looks like your control is "textBox1" with a capital B.

Comment: @JeremiahCrosby C# is case-sensitive I miss-typed the capital letters where they need to be so in your code textbox1 should be "textBox1.Text.Split("+");" and int32 should be "Int32.TryParse();"  I revised the code example above.